# How to change exiting aws snapshot tag name using python?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto3

I'm trying to change the existing AWS EBS Snapshots name but it seems that there is no method is available through which we can change the tag names, can anyone please help me on this?

Thanks

Comment: Are you saying that you want to change the Value of the Tag that has `Key = 'Name'`?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein yes you're right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call [`create_tags()`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Client.create_tags), specifying the ID of the EBS Snapshot:

```py
response = client.create_tags(
    Resources=['snapshot-1234'],
    Tags=[
        {
            'Key': 'Name',
            'Value': 'name-you-want-to-store'
        },
    ]
)
```